# remove colon from the first column of matching lines

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I am creating shell script to change cpu affinity in debian box. here is the sample output of `cat /proc/interrupts`

```
          CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3

39:  522718016          0          0          0   xen-dyn-event     eth0
40: 1492310505          0          0          0   xen-dyn-event     eth1
41: 1834986298          0          0          0   xen-dyn-event     eth2
```

I would like to store value of 1st column where the row matches eth1 and eth2 in variable because value could vary from machine to machine. I tried this

```
$ awk '{if ($7 == "eth1") print $1;}' /proc/interrupts 
40:
```

I just want to store number without colon or any other special character. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use Awk's Substitution String Function

There's more than one way to do this, but one simple way is to remove the unwanted character with the *sub* [string function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html). For example:

```
$ awk '$7 == "eth1" {sub(":", "", $1); print $1}' /proc/interrupts
40
```

### Alternative: Delete Characters with *tr*

Alternatively, if you don't need the whole solution to be in awk, you can also use the standard *tr* utility to delete unwanted characters. For example:

```
$ tr -d ':' < /proc/interrupts | awk '$7 == "eth1" {print $1}'
40
```

or:

```
$ { tr -d ':' | awk '$7 == "eth1" {print $1}'; } < /proc/interrupts
40
```

This isn't better or faster, but may come in handy when you want to filter your results *before* passing the results on to your awk script.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{if ($7 == "eth1") {split($1,a,":");print a[1]}}' /proc/interrupts
18
```

In `awk` there is an inbuilt function `split` which can split any field into chunks based on any defined delimiter. Here, `$1` is split into parts and based on `:` as delimiter and stored in an array `a[]`

or, but at cost of leading space.

```
awk -F:  '/eth1/{print $1}' /proc/interrupts
```

Answer (score 1):

With `grep` if `pcre` option is available:

```
$ grep -oP '^\s*\K\d+(?=.*eth1$)' /proc/interrupts 
40
```

Or `sed`

```
$ sed -nE '/eth1$/ s/^\s*([0-9]+).*/\1/p' /proc/interrupts
40
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
awk '$7=="eth1"{print $1+0}' /proc/interrupts
```

From [gawk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Strings-And-Numbers.html) Manual:

> If, for some reason, you need to force a number to be converted to a string, concatenate that number with the empty string, "". To force a string to be converted to a number, add zero to that string. A string is converted to a number by interpreting any numeric prefix of the string as numerals: "2.5" converts to 2.5, "1e3" converts to 1,000, and "25fix" has a numeric value of 25. Strings that can’t be interpreted as valid numbers convert to zero.